# How to transfer DataFrames from Pycharm through AWS EC2 to AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, pycharm

I developed a program written in Python in the Pycharm IDE that scrapes stock news' websites and saves data in a pandas DataFrame. I convert the data to a CSV file and currently save it to a folder on my desktop.

> However, I would like to save these CSV files directly to my AWS
>   account to an S3 bucket.

*I have downloaded the AWS Toolkit and set it up, however when opening my Pycharm Python project, I do not know how I can save the CSVs through AWS EC2 to AWS S3.*

Answer (score 1):

Use AWS' own [`boto3` python library](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) to set up an [S3 client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client) or [resource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#service-resource), which each have methods on them to transfer objects to your S3 bucket(s), eg (from quick-start):

```
# create an S3 resource
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
# Upload a new file
data = open('test.csv', 'rb')
s3.Bucket('my-bucket').put_object(Key='test.csv', Body=data)
```